How to mock k6/http while writing unit test using jest?
I have a file written in typescript and i need to write unit test for the mentioned methods using jest but the methods call k6/http so how do I mock them in jest?
I tried creating a separate mock directory and created k6 as well as k6/http files in order to mock the behavior of http calls but while running jest test it didn't recognize the mapping also if there is any alternative solution?

Could you provide the source code you need to write tests for?

Why are you writing tests for your tests? :)
